# Multidimensional array partial assignment in VHDL

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, vhdl, variable-assignment

I declared 2 types of array:

```
typeA is array(0 to 15) of std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
typeB is array(0 to 7) of std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
```

Then I instantiated 3 signals:

```
X1 : typeA;
X2, X3 : typeB;
```

I would like to assign the first 8 vectors of X1 to X2, the others to X2:

```
X2 <= X1(0 to 7);
X3 <= X1(8 to 15);
```

But I get an error because the right part of the assignment is not the same as the left one, but the dimensions are supposed to match. What is the correct way of doing it?

Comment: Neither typeA nor typeB are multidimensional array types, they have only one index(IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.3.2.1) Without showing declarations providing object class (6.5.6.3) X2 and X3 are targets of signal assignment statements(10.5) - they are class signal and not class variable, signals are updated and have history (Annex I Glossary), variable assignment is immediate (10.6). The multidimensional-array and variable-assignment tags are not appropriate for your VHDL snippets (which do not comprise a [mcve], also lacking the actual error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that TypeA and TypeB are different (although similar) types, so you cannot directly assign one to the other. Because they are similar (they are both arrays of the same subtype), you are allowed to cast from one type to the other.

`X2 <= typeB(X1(0 to 7));`

An easier fix for this might be just to declare the type as unconstrained, and constrain it at the declaration:

```
type slv16_array_t is array(natural range <>) of std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);

X1: slv16_array_t(0 to 15);
X2: slv16_array_t(0 to 7);

X2 <= X1(0 to 7); -- these are the same type already, so can be assigned to each other without a cast
```